# How I can analyze and present docking results?

Tags: binding-energy, docking, glide

I did a docking job and got a score of -5.69 kcal/mol and a value for MM-GBSA of -60 kcal/mol.

I should analyze these results for my thesis but do not know how to comment on them. Does anyone have any insight about what this number might mean?

Also on interactions, I wonder what can be said? Are there plots of the data that would be appropriate to include?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can analyze your docking results in two ways.

First way is looking for the score function your program uses. For some score functions, lower value indicates better interactions and for others, higher values indicate better interactions. Also,, look for the decomposition of the score. Normally, the score is composed by different type of interaction/penalties like Coulomb electrostatic interaction, van der Waals interaction, H-bond interaction, etc. This partition scheme will help you to understand which is the main mechanism of interaction between your ligand and the protein.
**This should be the main way to get conclusions about how the interaction occurs.**

The second way is by visually inspecting the 2D Interaction diagram. To produce those diagrams, you need to use another software like [Maestro](https://www.schrodinger.com/maestro), [LigPlot+](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/software/LigPlus/), [LeView](http://www.pegase-biosciences.com/leview-ligand-environment-viewer/),  [PoseView](https://www.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/en/forschung/amd/server/poseview.html), and 
[Protein-Ligand Interaction Profiler](https://projects.biotec.tu-dresden.de/plip-web/plip) just to cite a few.
**Not all the relevant information about the interactions is shown in this 2D diagrams.**

Comment: Many thanks. At moment I just use maestro suite

Comment: In this case can  I tell that, even though, the docking score is not very good the mm-gbsa shown that my ligand could be taken into conideration as a possible Inhibitor of my target? – Anastasia01 12 mins ago   Delete

Comment: If you did the docking using Maestro, you had used one of two methods, GLIDE or IFD (that uses GLIDE). GLIDE is a well tested docking software that its results are reliable even when the protein is kept fixed. On the other hand, IFD gave some flexibility to the protein. So, having positive values of g-score (GLIDE Score) is a bad sign.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The  glide score is -5,600.

Comment: Being negative is good. As GLIDE score is roughly a binding free energy, converting it to dissociation constant Kd = exp(deltaG/(R*T)), here deltaG = GLIDE score, T=300K, R is the Universal gas constant. Some times, the dissociation constant is similar to inhibition constant.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8):

Docking results can be analyzed in a number of ways by looking at various geometric parameters, such as a distances, angles and dihedrals. These are then typically compared against "ideal" values, such as a those at the transition state. Graphs typically contain a parameter on each axis with the results and ideal points plotted. Interactions can mean various things, such as H-bonds and pi-interactions. *Comment made before revisions to initial question*

Comment: Thank you so much, but i don't undestand if my score is good or not in relation to the result of mm-gbsa

Comment: I am so sorry but I am a beginner and i have much thing to learn

Comment: @Anastasia01 No problem, we all have to start somewhere! One thing to keep in mind with docking, the best pose is not always the reactive pose. As far as precision goes for these calculations, they are typically system dependent in their ability to be accurate. A lot of care has to go into setting the system up to get accurate results.

Comment: @Anastasia01 Results also get trickier to interpret when a non-native ligand is studied. Comparisons to the native ligand will be required, or a reference ligand if the native is not known.

Comment: You cannot compare the score with the MM-GBSA. Also, you can not compare the score obtained with different software.

Comment: @I.Camps Very good point, thanks for making the clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't a native ligand but a reference ligand and about this i Have onother question. Whaen I running a docking job on reference ligand this one don't bind the residue that is known on litterature. The ligand sholud be bind a specific residue according to litterature but in my job not. Can you explain me whay?

Comment: This will likely depend on your docking parameters, such as box size and flexibility.

Comment: I running a SP docking with glide, as force field OPLS5 and as centroid of my grid i select the known residue involved in allosteric bind.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to proceed is to use a control in your experiment as with modelling experiment in general.
You can, for example, use the co-crystalized ligand or a well-know inhibitor (something experimentally established with IC50 value for example) of your protein of interest. The values obtained with that ligand in your docking/MMGBSA calculations will serve as guide for comparison...